# Syntax error in script when generating policyid

Tags: cardano-cli, transaction, policy

On Windows I'm trying to mint some NFTs on Cardano testnet using [this guide](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting-nfts/).

The problem is that when I'm trying to generate policyID I'm getting this error even though the JSON is valid:

```
cardano-cli transaction policyid --script-file policy.script >> policyID
Command failed: transaction policyid  Error: policy.script: Syntax error in script: Error in $: Failed reading: not a valid json value
```

Script is here:

```
{
  "scripts": [
    {
      "type": "before",
      "slot": 37102595
    },
    {
      "type": "sig",
      "keyHash": "5d4b345b91acf751d7d591f327c10c731024f25db6daed4cabdXXXXX"
    }
  ],
  "type": "all"
}
```

At first I thought it was some Windows distro bug, but after rebuilding 1.29 version from source on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (ran over wsl 2) I get the same error.

Out of desperation I also tried removing all spaces like I read in some other answers to similar error when using cardano-cli, that didn't help.

Comment: Were you able to resolve it. if yes what was the issue

Comment: If you put a correct key hash it works.

Comment: Just in case this might be useful for you or for others Typhon Wallet Dapp Connector supports Minting tokens/NFTs using NativeScript using a simple method. ```js
const receivingAddress = "addr_test1qz2qzz8d4unvpkes7nt7tjkwx0sff3cfkrvl528mgkdzt5kmt68vuzvz4nzgs00x0shrgywvy674v6r2zcs8fxvvq27qqycj9a"; const decoded = typhonjs.utils.decodeBech32(receivingAddress);
const pubKeyHash = decoded.value.slice(2, 56 + 2); const nativeScript = { pubKeyHash: pubKeyHash,
};
const nativeScriptFactory = new typhonjs.NativeScriptFactory(nativeScript);
const policyId = nativeScriptFactory.policyId().toString("hex